# Access the cell outputs from a synapse notebook using a (python) synapse api

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, azure-notebooks, azure-synapse-pipeline

We need to perform post-processing on all pipeline runs including evaluating the output of each cell.  The intent is to audit  the cell outputs directly - not to generate emails or other new artifacts.

A primary use case is to allow both automated and manual in-depth troubleshooting based on the notebook cell contents including examining many individual log entries as well as stacktraces.

Since the notebook could fail in one of a number of cells we would be looking for an API that allows access to the cell-level structure of the notebook output.

There is a related question here, however that question is dealing with generating an email to send specific results:  [Easily access notebook output run in Synapse pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75862049/easily-access-notebook-output-run-in-synapse-pipeline) .   Instead we want the entire notebook outputs organized by sequential cell number via the `azure` api.  How can this be done?

**Update**  A promising lead is via the `Azure REST API` and specifically the `output` of  [Activity Runs - Query By Pipeline Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP) .  I am working through how to set up the REST URL to try it out.

Comment: Correct me  if i am wrong you want to know how to view output of each cell of a synapse notebook which gets executed ?

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula yes

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the details of your scheduled pipeline's notebook run in the "**Pipeline Runs**" section under the "**Monitor**" tab.
click on the option that says 'Open Notebook snapshot,' which is represented by an icon resembling spectacles.

I have debugged the pipeline and also I have triggered the pipeline:
[image]

I have set up a notebook and linked it to the scheduled trigger, allowing me to see the results of each cell in the monitor tab.
To view the output, navigate to the "`Monitor`" application option under the pipeline run, choose the "`Logs`" tab, and examine the output in the "`stdout`" menu.

The below is the output for each indvidual cell.
[image]

[image]

Once you click on the spectacles you will see like below
[image]

[image]
Please note that instead of writing text into stdout using the usual method, you can opt for the `print()` function.
For additional information,[Known more about Limitations Azure Synapse Analytics.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-development-using-notebooks#known-limitations)

As you mentioned You want the solution outputs programmatically to access the cell-level structure of a notebook's output using the Azure REST API
The below are the following steps:

**Step 1:** You will have to obtain the pipeline run ID

**SETP 2:** Create the **HTTP** **GET**

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/{workspaceName}/pipelineruns/{pipelineRunId}/activityruns?api-version=2019-06-01-preview
```

**Step 3:** Send a GET request to the **REST URL** to retrieve the activity runs for the pipeline run.

you can extract the cell-level output by iterating over the value array and accessing the output field of each activity run.

Comment: The entire point of the question is to access these outputs programmatically, not manually through a UI

Comment: Let me try that at my end and will update you in the comments.